# MySQL database table to HTML table

Tags: php, mysql, html

Here the value of $table will be passed from another file and it will be a table name in a database.

With that table name ($table) am trying to fetch its column names and all the values in the table and make the table look like an actual one we see in phpMyAdmin.

As a result of the code below. I can only get the column names. But not the data. Please tell me what should i do to perform the task of showing the datas in the table

```
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="display" rel="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>


    <?php
    //echo"select * from $table";
    $qq=mysql_query("show columns from $table");
    if(mysql_num_rows($qq)>0){
    //$i=1;
    echo '<tr>';
        while($rs = mysql_fetch_row($qq))
        {
        $sel=mysql_query("select * from $table");
        $fetch=mysql_fetch_object($sel);
        //while($fetch=mysql_fetch_object($sel))
        //{
        ?>  
            <td><?php echo $fetch->$rs[0];?></td>
    <?php
        //}
    //$i++;
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    else    
    {
    ?>      
            <tr>
                <td colspan="11">No data to display</td>
            </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: exact duplicate of [Got stuck with populating mysql table in html table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358187/got-stuck-with-populating-mysql-table-in-html-table)

Comment: Let's hope [little boby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) doesn't come here

Comment: @pin isn't it dangerous? is there any protection?

Comment: @Col Tought `$table` was user input, nevermind

Comment: @pin why nevermind? what if it's really from user input? What if it's name like `monthly reports`?

Comment: @Col, i think you already know... You can escape user input with [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), or use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @pin care to try either method you suggested and see if it helps even a bit here?

Comment: @pin I've been writing it thousands times already, but of course with no effect. First, these 2 methods you suggested has absolutely nothing to do with user input. It's just SQL formatting facilities. And should be used **regardless** of data source. While table name is another matter and  mysql_real_escape_string() will help nothing as there are no quotes around while PDO prepared statements will merely throw an error if you rty to bind a table name

Answer (score 0):

Yes only columns will be printing because you are printing $rs[0];?> where $rs holds object for mysql_query qq and it holds your column query only not

```
"select * from $table"
```

this.

Why dont you try displaying columns as a single row in html table and then try displaying data from other php set with seperate query structure .
Hope this way it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I coudn't fix your code because it was getting ugly, so i remade it:

**php:**

```
function mysql_fetch_all($res) {
    $result = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }
    return $result;
}

function getColumnsAndData($table) {
    $table = mysql_real_escape_string($table);
    $q1 = mysql_query("show columns from $table");
    $q2 = mysql_query("select * from $table");
    return array(mysql_fetch_all($q1), mysql_fetch_all($q2));
}

list($columns, $data) = getColumnsAndData($table);
?>
```

**html**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="display" rel="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
                <td><?php echo $column[0] . ' ' . $column[1] ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php if (count($data) > 0): ?>
            <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
                <tr>
                    <?php foreach ($row as $value): ?>
                        <td><?php echo $value ?></td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else: ?>
            <tr>
                <td>No data to display</td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```