# Got stuck with populating mysql table in html table

Tags: php, mysql, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL database table to HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357984/mysql-database-table-to-html-table)

Here the value of $table will be passed from another file and it will be a table name in a database.

With that table name ($table) am trying to fetch its column names and all the values in the table and make the table look like an actual one we see in phpMyAdmin.

As a result of the code below. I can only get the column names. But not the data. Please tell me what should i do to perform the task of showing the datas in the table

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="display" rel="datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>


        <?php
        //echo"select * from $table";
        $qq=mysql_query("show columns from $table");
        if(mysql_num_rows($qq)>0){
        //$i=1;
        echo '<tr>';
            while($rs = mysql_fetch_row($qq))
            {
            $sel=mysql_query("select * from $table");
            $fetch=mysql_fetch_object($sel);
            //while($fetch=mysql_fetch_object($sel))
            //{
            ?>  
                <td><?php echo $fetch->$rs[0];?></td>
        <?php
            //}
        //$i++;
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        else    
        {
        ?>      
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="11">No data to display</td>
                </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>  
        </tbody>
    </table>
```